# using python how do you check if a channel with a certain name exists in a specific category?

Tags: python, discord.py

right now i have a discord server with a category and a command that makes a new channel in that category. but i want it to only make the new channel if the category currently does not have the name of the new channel. i've looked through the discord.py documentation a few times for an answer but haven't found anything. how would i achieve this? thank you

Comment: You say you are "using python" but are looking at "discord.js documentation". I don't understand, which are you using: python or javascript? Discord.js uses javascript, as seen by the ".js". The python libraries are different, such as discord.py. You need to edit your question to set the right tags and identify the right programming language. Whichever you are using, just look at the library's documentation. It probably goes along the lines of finding the `channel.name` inside the `category.children` collection/list.

Comment: oh yes I meant discord.py

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about discord.py and have never used it, but this information appears to be pretty simple to find on the discord.py docs. Discord.py appears to have a utility function for getting, for example, a channel by name from a list of channels (exactly what you are looking for).

```py
channel = discord.utils.get(category.text_channels, name='channel_name')

if not channel:
  # Create the new channel
```

This utility gets the first channel amongst the category's text channels that has a name matching `'channel_name'`, and if the utility is not able to find such a channel, it returns `None`. Thus, you can check for this latter case and only create the new channel if the `channel` of the given name is not found.

If the channel you are creating can be of any type, and not just a text channel, then use `category.channels` instead of `category.text_channels`.

References:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel.text_channels
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get